# How can I specify a column alias in HQL so I can use AliasToBeanResultTransformer with Count

Tags: nhibernate, hql

Using NHibernate, I would like to run the following query:

```
return Session.CreateQuery<FooSummary>(
    @"select FooType, count(*) as Total from Foo
      group by FooType")
    .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(FooSummary)))
    .List<FooSummary>();
```

The classess are:

```
class FooSummary { string FooType, int Total };
class Foo { string FooType };
```

However, it seems that HQL doesn't support column aliases. Is this correct? If so, does that mean I can't use AliasToBeanResultTransformer?

Comment: Hi, what is FooType? Please post mappings for FooType.

Answer (score 2):

It **does** support aliases:

```
select FooType FooType,
       count(*) Total
from Foo
group by FooType
```

Are you getting any errors with this query? If so, post the full exception.

Comment: this alias is not sent to the DB

Comment: @Jaguar: it's transparent. The purpose of the alias is to map things *client side*. Why would you care about the aliases sent to the DB?

Comment: i shouldn't care, but in my -limited- testing "Total", the column alias that you define in the hql does not arrive in the result transformer. i used to get the nhibernate-generated alias so the result couldn't get mapped to the provided type property

Comment: @Jaguar: do you have a proof of concept of that bug?

Comment: well i was testing some queries from mapped entities to produce some kind of dto's, but no nothing small enough to place as a bug report. when i have time i'll revisit it

Comment: Hi, here is the exception I am getting: NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException : Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. near line 1, column 17 [select FirstName FirstName, 
count(*) Total from Domain.Employee 
group by FirstName]

Comment: try `select FirstName as FirstName, count(*) as Total from Employee group by FirstName`. If that works, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

up until nhibernate 2.1.2 **column** aliasing in hql is borked. It works on very specific scenarios but it's not to be trusted